# sed delete line containing date

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing a huge (3400+ lines) list of URLs, each of which looks something like this:

```
http://examplesite/rn/index.php?PageID=SF01_02_01&ID=2015-12-23-0012
```

What I would like to do is use `sed` to select all lines containing today's date.

What I've been trying is:

```
datetoday=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
sed "/$datetoday/!d" en.html
```

However, this seems to blank the file suggesting that no lines match the string. Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks OK. Seems grep would be simpler: `grep -F "$(date +%F)" en.html`

Comment: ...is the file actually HTML?

Comment: +1 for glenn's suggestion, and to add to it .. you might wan to include the field name in the query string too.  `grep -F "ID=$(date +%F)" filename`.  Just in case there are other parts of the URL that accidentally match the date.

Comment: Glenn's suggestion works great! Thank you! Ghoti, the dates match the filenames, though that is a good precaution, thank you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flag `p` instead `d`:

`sed -n "/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/p" en.html`

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU awk instead of 2 separate commands:

```
awk '$0~strftime("%F")'
```